# compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))-\sin(\sin(x))}{\tan(\tan(x))-\tan(\sin(x))}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need help with this problem as stated in the title:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))-\sin(\sin(x))}{\tan(\tan(x))-\tan(\sin(x))}$$

I'm trying to convert the problem to using only the standard limits, with that said, I'm trying to solve the problem without using L'Hospital nor any Maclaurin series.

Do you guys have any tips on how to tackle the problem as I'm really struggling with this one.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out my [article](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123) on taylor series. I tried to explain it such that a highschooler could understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternate approach:**

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\sin(\sin x)}{\tan(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)} &= \frac{2\sin(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2})\cos(\frac{\tan x+\sin x}{2})}{\frac{\sin(\tan x-\sin x)}{\cos(\tan x)\cos(\sin x)}} \\
&= \frac{2\sin(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2})\cos(\frac{\tan x+\sin x}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2})\cos(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2})}\cdot \cos(\tan x)\cos(\sin x) \\
&= \frac{\cos(\frac{\tan x+\sin x}{2})}{\cos(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2})}\cdot \cos(\tan x)\cos(\sin x)
\end{align}

and its limit as $x\to0$ can be evaluated easily.

Comment: Wow! That's a very nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: This is indeed a very nice alternative. For the denominator we can also use that $\tan(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)=(\tan(\tan x-\sin x))(1+\tan(\tan x)\tan(\sin x))$.

Comment: Nice, but not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2476571/42969.

Answer (score 1):

We can manipulate the given expression as follows

$$\frac{\sin(\tan(x))-\sin(\sin(x))}{\tan(\tan(x))-\tan(\sin(x))}=\frac{\frac1{\cos^3x }\frac{\sin(\tan(x))-\tan x}{\tan^3 x}-\frac{\sin(\sin(x))-\sin x}{\sin^3 x}+\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3 x}}{\frac1{\cos^3x }\frac{\tan(\tan(x))-\tan x}{\tan^3 x}-\frac{\tan(\sin(x))-\sin x}{\sin^3 x}+\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3 x}}$$

then we can use that as $x \to 0$

$$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\to -\frac16$$

$$\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\to \frac13$$

with the methods indicated here:

- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

Comment: Thank you alot! But how in the world did you even come up with that manipulation of the expression. I see that's truly effective, but how? I'd never come up with such a thing, ever :)

Comment: @Tanamas As a first step you need to become confident with standard limits and then try to manipulate the expression to make emerge them. When the order involved is the first this always works well. Here we need to refer to higher order standard" limits to obtain the result but the way to proceed is the same.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tip! Do you got any "resources" in terms of links where I can find more challenging limits like these?

Comment: @Tanamas I don't have specific resources to indicate other than MSE, you can find other similar limits here.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will use some trigonometric identities and the standard limits $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}y =1 \text{ and } \lim_{y\to 0}\frac y{\tan y} =1\tag 1$$
Using $\sin C-\sin D=2\cos \frac{D+C}2\sin \frac{C-D}2$, numerator of the given expression becomes: $$2\sin \Big(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2}\Big)\cos \frac{\tan x+\sin x}{2}\tag 2$$
Using $\tan A- \tan B=(1+\tan A\tan B)\tan (A-B)$, denominator of the given expression becomes $$(1+\tan(\tan x)\tan(\sin x))\tan (\tan x-\sin x)\tag 3$$

So re-writing the given expression using $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ gives:
$$2\frac{\cos (\frac{\tan x+\sin x}{2})}{1+\tan(\tan x)\tan(\sin x)}.\frac{\sin \Big(\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2}\Big)}{\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2}}.\frac{\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{2}}{\tan x-\sin x}.\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\tan (\tan x-\sin x)}\tag 4$$

By $(1)$, the first two terms in $(4)$ have limits (as $x\to 0$) $2$ and $1$ respectively and the last term has limit $1$ as $x\to 0$. The third term has limit equal to $\frac 12$ as $x\to 0$ so by limit rules the limit of the given expression is $2\times 1 \times \frac 12 \times 1=1$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score -1):

[Link to the answer image please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hk48.png)

The answer that i got for this problem is 1 without using L-Hospital or Maclurian series.